# host win10 can ping guest centos6 but centos6 cannot ping win10?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, centos, ping

I use Wifi at home and my Virtualbox network mode is bridge adapter + promiscuous

centos 6 network information is

[image]
[image]
[image]

Winows10 can ping guest centos6

[image]

and I can use secureCRT to conncet to centos6
[image]

but centos 6 cannot ping windows10 or other webstie

centos6:192.168.56.102

win10:  192.168.1.105

[image]

what should I do ? thank you very much

Comment: Slightly off-topic remark: why are you logging in as root?

Comment: @oldmud0 because root makes me feel powerful like a Spiderman :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## One or both of these two things are probably blocking you.

1. The windows firewall has three Classifications, Domain, Private, and Public. By default ICMP Type=Echo is disabled on the windows firewall for all classifications.
2. Sometimes the network, which is the software side of the hardware interface doesn't get properly assigned to a firewall classification. Out bound communication will still work, but incoming rules will work inconsistently.

### To solve the first:

Open the Windows Firewall from Control Panel or wf.msc from the search box and right-click to run as Administrator.

Under Inbound Rules, enable the rules your need:

```
   File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)
   File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv6-In)
```

You may want to change the properties on each rule (right click -> properties) Advanced Tab, to limit the scope the rule apples to by removing Public.

### To solve the second:

Sometimes windows doesn't properly assign the network connection to the proper network classification automatically.

The last comment from [Itai Shaham](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0652e827-650d-4b20-afe5-d2112e830875/cannot-rdp-into-windows-10-from-windows-7?forum=WinPreview2014General) on this locked TechNet thread will probably fix the issue for you.

1. Open gpedit.msc
2. Goto Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Network List Manager Policies
3. Find the Network Name of your network connection on the right side of the window (may be just Network) and double-click it to open its Network Properties dialog
4. Goto the Network Location tab and change the “Location Type” to "Private"

**Security issue:** If this is **NOT** a system that will see multiple networks change, e.g. something with wireless or a laptop **and** you have a private network showing as *Unidentified Network*, step 3b would be to move **all** current and future *Unidentified Networks* into the classification of your choice.

*Unidentified Network* appears when windows can't find the defined gateway on that interface.

Comment: I found this unanswered question while looking for a similar issue. Once I fixed it, this was how. My problem was with ping and Windows RDP and not allowing a connection from win7 to Win10 with NLA security enabled. The ping still didn't work between networks but did work in the local network until I did the second step.